# Как передать аргумент в конструктор для инициализации приватного свойства?

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection

Есть контроллер:

```php
class ShapeController extends Controller {

  private $model;
  private $shape;

  public function __construct(Shape $model, ShapeClass $shape ) {
    $this->model = $model;
    $this->shape = $shape;
  }
}
```

Есть класс:

```php
class Shape {

  private $shape;

  public function __construct(ShapeModel $shape) {
    $this->shape = $shape;
  }

}
```

Как мне сказать **Laravel**, что при создании класса Shape передай в конструктор модель(`$this->model`)?

Comment: хм, если это не интерфейс, то DIC ларавеля сам прокинет тебе нужный клас без надобности регистрировать его. То есть у тебя тут все должно работать.

Comment: @UKRman Не работает. Потому что `ShapeModel $shape` в классе `Shape` не равна модели контроллера. Очень не хочется писать метод в классе `Shape` аля `updateShapeModel`...

Comment: А ```ShapeModel``` наследует ларавеловский актив рекорд?

Comment: @UKRman `ShapeModel extends Model` - если вы про это.